# Get rid of iOS-Safari smart app download banner

Tags: ios, safari, smart-app-banner

When I open my website in iOS-Safari it shows a [Smart App Download Banner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners) but the problem is we have implemented our own custom download banner which works perfectly fine. In case of iOS-Safari two banner appears

1. [Smart App Download Banner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners)
2. Our custom banner

Surprisngly, we do not have this tag in our code

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, app-argument=myURL">
```

It seems that iOS automatic displays it as we have some universal link registered. We are looking for a way to get rid of this iOS default Smart App Download Banner as We want to show our custom banner only.

Comment: Exactly the same situation. Any news on this?